# Flask Max Recursion Depth

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, flask, depth

I have a `max recursion depth` error that is driving me nuts

In the flask `__init__.py` file I have:

```
@app.route('/vpcs')
@app.route('/vpcs/<vpc>')
def getVPCs(vpc=False):
    """
    Get the vpcs.
    """
    results = getVPCs()
    return jsonify(**results)
```

It calls the functions from:

```
def getVPCs():
   """
   This is the function that loops through the accounts and regions and does all the connections.
   """
```

A function that loops through the config file with the account keys

```
   accounts = getAccountCreds()

   vpc_list = []
   try:
```

Loop through each region ...
         # for each region
         for r in REGIONS:

Loop through each of the accounts

```
       # for each of the 8,yes 8, AWS accounts...
       for account,keys in accounts.iteritems():
         conn = VPCConnection(region=ec2.get_region(r),aws_access_key_id=keys[0],aws_secret_access_key=keys[1])
```

Get all the VPCs for each account ...

```
          vpcs = conn.get_all_vpcs()
          if formatVPC(account,vpcs[0]):
                vpc_list.append(formatVPC(account,vpcs[0]))
            return vpc_list
  except boto.exception.BotoServerError, e:
    print e
```

Which also calls:

```
def formatVPC(account,instance):
    """
    Function to format VPC data. 
    Keys we want: 
    - id
    - instance_tenancy
    - tags
    - region.name
    - region.connection
    - region.endpoint
    - state
    - cidr_block
    """
    result_dict = {}
    if instance:
        result_dict['account'] = account
        result_dict['id'] = instance.id
        result_dict['cidr_block'] = instance.cidr_block
        result_dict['instance_tenancy'] = instance.instance_tenancy
        result_dict['region'] = {'name':instance.region.name,'connection':   instance.region.connection,'endpoint':instance.region.endpoint}

        if result_dict:
            return result_dict
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
```

Comment: `getVPCs()` calls itself forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It calls the functions from:

Nope, the `getVPCs` from your snippet just calls itself:

```
@app.route('/vpcs')
@app.route('/vpcs/<vpc>')
def getVPCs(vpc=False):
    """
    Get the vpcs.
    """
    results = getVPCs()  # Here.
    return jsonify(**results)
```

and does so recursively, without any "boundary" other than [recursion limit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit), which results in [RuntimeError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError): `maximum recursion depth exceeded`you've mentioned.

Change one of these functions' names (and, of course, adjust the call if necessary).

Answer (score -3):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

sys.getrecursionlimit()
Return the current value of the recursion limit, the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python. It can be set by setrecursionlimit().